# Alert after touch in UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a `UIView` with several `UILabel`. Now I want to add an alert when the `UIView` has been clicked. Is a click event on a view possible?

Thats my unfinished code:

```
class viewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var view2: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var view3: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func action(_ sender: UIView) {
    // Create the alert controller
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)

    // Create the actions
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "title", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
    }

    // Add the actions
    alertController.addAction(okAction)

    // Present the controller
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
} 
}
```

The function `action` should look like my example. Now I need to know how to call it and refer it to the `UIView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In your `viewDidLoae`, add a silenter

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (viewClicker(sender:)))
self.view1.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

Then catch your click action in this function

```
func viewClicker(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // Do what you want
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can override **touchesBegan** method when clicking specific controls. Instead of checking tag you can directly compare UIView

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        switch touch.view? {
           case self.view1:
                      // show alert
                       break
           case self.view2:
                      // show alert
                       break
           case self.view3:
                      // show alert
                       break
           default:
                   break
        }

    }
}
```